# Conditional Compilation with Create React App

Tags: create-react-app, conditional-compilation

I'm working on an application that is written in TypeScript and built with Create React App (CRA). The application needs buttons for reseting various things, so people carrying out manual software testing can do their job. How can I convince CRA to leave the test functionalities out when compiling a production build? I wouldn't want to leave a "loaded gun" behind a simple `if` statement and a runtime configuration option that might accidentally be turned on one day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is a good practice, but I would have place these buttons with some html tags like data-test-show and hide them (display none or something).

On the test environment I would add some css styles for that attribute to show such elements.